# VisualVM "Sampler->Cpu->CpuSettings" is grayed out. How come?

Tags: java, visualvm

I am unable to filter what specific packages I want to look at, since the cpusettings menu is grayed out.

I am running my application from eclipse using the VisualVM runner.

Answer (score 3):

CPU settings cannot be changed when a sampling is in progress. Set them before you start CPU sampling.

Comment: If you've had profiling running, sometimes it takes a while for the stop to take effect and the settings to become enabled.